# ng-class property not working for directive but working for raw code?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-class

I'm trying to refactor an Angular app which is very verbose using directives.  As part of the page layout, there is a faux-tab browsing experience (looks like tabs, is actually implemented as normal links) which is the focus of the refactoring.  I was successfully able to create a directive called tabbedNav to hold the container of the tabs.  I am trying to create a directive to hold the individual tab-links:

```
.directive("tabHeader", function(){
        return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<li ng-class="{\'my_css_class\': pageName === \'{{flag}}\' }"><a ng-href = {{url}} ng-transclude></a></li>',
        scope: {
            flag: '@',
            url: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {}
    }
})
```

This is used in code as follows:

```
<tabbed-nav>
    <tab-header flag="value1" url="value2">some text here</tab-header>
</tabbed-nav>
```

It should be noted that the value pageName is set in my controller as:

```
$scope.pageName = value1;
```

The idea is that the tab header is present on every page, and each page has an ID; for each tab (every tab is present on every page), if the page ID is equal to the tab's flag value, then the CSS is set, otherwise it's not.

The issue I'm running into is that, while the href value of the anchor gets set properly, the CSS styling set by the ng-class does not (yes, I have quadruple-checked that the flag value is set correctly).  However, when I replace the tab-header tag with the raw HTML in the template (replacing flag and url with their actual values) as follows, then everything works fine:

```
<tabbed-nav>
    <li ng-class="{'my_css_class': pageName === 'value1' }">
        <a ng-href = "value2" ng-transclude>
            some text here
        </a>
    </li>
</tabbed-nav>
```

The reason I want to implement this as a directive is because I intend to have many tab-headers on the page and I would like to reuse this directive many times.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use expression with `{{}}`(interpolation) inside `ng-class`, it will throw an error. Even the quotes are not needful there. it should look like below

```
'<li ng-class="{\'my_css_class\': pageName === flag }"><a ng-href = {{url}} ng-transclude></a></li>'
```

Also since you're using `isolatedScope` for your directive, `pageName` value wouldn't be reachable inside your directive. You have to pass the `pageName` to directive as binding.

[**Check Plunker**](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/7NrXPpnM7LkfUYJC?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.  When I check the page source in developer console, where it had the value of the flag before, now it doesn't, it just has "flag" as a literal.  Also, there are no errors thrown the existing way, it just doesn't work.

Comment: I appear to have missed a detail (I will comment here as well as edit my OP): pageName is set in my controller as $scope.pageName.

Comment: This answer missed a few details, but it did set me on the right track to finding the answer I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: What more details you need??

Comment: Your comment about isolated scope helped me out.  When I Googled what that meant in the context of importing values into a directive, I got the answer I needed in a tutorial I found.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was not aware of the impacts of scoping in Angular.  My directive was unable to read my page-level scope field directly, and I had to pass the page-level field into the directive as well.  This seems awkward, but this seems to be how it needs to be done.

Working code:

```
.directive("tabHeader", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<li ng-class="{\'my_css_class\': \'{{scope-value}}\' === \'{{flag}}\' }"><a ng-href = {{url}} ng-transclude></a></li>',
        scope: {
            flag: '@',
            url: '@',
            scope-value: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {}
    }
})
```

and HTML:

```
<tab-header 
    flag="value1" 
    url="value2" 
    scope-value={{value-from-controller-scope}}>
        text here
</tab-header>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, in case I forget to revisit this question to mark is as such.